# How to connect node.js localhost at port 80 with apache mysql at port 90?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, apache

I'm trying to access a mysql database using node.js. I simply run the following command in cmd prompt:

```
C:\rest-server> node bin/www
```

and it displays this message:

```
Express server listening in port 80
```

and I've the .js file as follows which the localhost access at port 80:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var async = require('async');

var util = require('../utils/util');
var db = require('../utils/database');
var connection = db.connection();

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.manager) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }

  if (req.query.tip == 'error') {
    var tip = 'username or password incorrect!';
  } else {
    var tip = null;
  }
  res.render('login', { tip: tip });
});

router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM restaurant_accounts WHERE ra_name=?';
  connection.query(sql, [username], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length == 0) {
      return res.redirect('/manager/login?tip=error');
    } 
    var account = result[0];
    if (!util.checkHash(password, account.ra_password)) {
      return res.redirect('/manager/login?tip=error');
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE rest_owner_id=?', [account.ra_id], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var restaurant = result[0];
      req.session.manager = {
        id: account.ra_id,
        name: account.ra_name,
        rest_id: restaurant.rest_id,
        rest_name: restaurant.rest_name
      };
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/manager/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I type localhost:80 on my browser it displays the following screen:

[image]

But ofcourse since the database is not linked, I can't get past this step and it shows the "**localhost** refused to connect" error!

I already have a .sql database with necessary tables created. How do I link these two so I can login from the login page?

EDIT: database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var c = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'bjtu',
  password : 'bjtu',
  database : 'restaurant'
});

// enable error logging for each connection query
c.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // example : 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

exports.connection = function() {
    return c;
};
```

**CONSOLE ERROR FOR SAMPLE.JS**

```
if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'me'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:51:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:103:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:136:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\utils\sample.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

The npm module [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) should do the trick.

Basic connect would look like this:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Probably soon you would like to have a look at [MongoDB.](https://www.mongodb.com/) Which you can connect to using module [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose), for example.

**Update:**

Try to set port to your connection object in database.js. Like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var c = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'bjtu',
  password : 'bjtu',
  database : 'restaurant',
  port     : 90
});

// enable error logging for each connection query
c.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // example : 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

exports.connection = function() {
    return c;
};
```

The default port is 3306, which doesnt look like your case :)

And I suggest you to look into mysql pools.

Comment: I've created a module database.js as shown in EDIT above, now how do I use this to login? The Express server access the 1st .js file above and doesn't accept the username and password from database.js Simply says "This site can't be reached. Localhost refused to connect." What am I missing here? Do I have to connect those two .js files in some way?

Comment: I ran the "node database.js" command in the console and it doesn't show any messages.  It waits for a min and shows the directory path again. Doesn't say connection established or anything. Please Help!

Comment: I dont see these console.logs in your database.js file. Your code looks close to working, I can suggest install node-inspector and debug your app.

Comment: Yes, MySQL is using port 3306 as shown by the wampserver. But whenever I do localhost:3306 in the browser, it just downloads an extensionless file and does nothing! Is something wrong there?

Comment: I used the node-inspector for database.js and at localhost:5858 it just shows the type:connect and v8, protocol versions etc.

Comment: Copy the example code of mysql module into separate file, run it, and define you have problem with js or mysql database itself.

Comment: I made a sample.js of the example code and it gave the above error in "CONSOLE ERROR FOR SAMPLE.JS". seems like a .js problem? What does it look like?

Comment: From error we see, that password/login dont fit. Install phpmyadmin(for example) or any other client, and check you login/pass pair. When you finish with that  - come back to your code.

Comment: I already have phpmyadmin as a client and I have created a database with several tables as well, where do you suggest I look for the login/pass pair? Perhaps it can be figured out from the first .js file above, which the express server actually accesses for the localhost:80.

Comment: harder, but correct way: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-account-management.html  . And simple - logout and try login back to define your pair.

Comment: Can't it be figured out from the first .js file above, which the express server actually accesses for the localhost:80 for finding which field in database is used for username and passeord?

Comment: From your error I see that you used login and password from the example, retry with your own.